# JavaScript - change class name

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/nokin3/690zrsv1/)

In my JSFiddle - my problem is

How I toggle and change class in the same time?

```
normal show "<" when click menu toggle and it show ">".
```

Comment: If you're referring to the JavaScript function togglesidebar() #mySidebar is toggling the active class.  #changeclass already has the classes "fa fa-chevron-right" so there's no change there.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if class is present in `classlist` and render icon accordingly

```js
function togglesidebar() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").classList.toggle('active');
  const isActive = document.getElementById("mySidebar").classList.contains('active')
  document.getElementById("changeclass").className = `fa fa-chevron-${isActive ? 'right' : 'left'}`;
}
```

```css
#mySidebar.active {
  right: 0px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

#mySidebar.active {
  right: 0px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

#mySidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  right: -7%;
  /* width: 100px;
            height: 200px; */
  width: 8.333333%;
  /* 100/1200 */
  /* 100/1200 */
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: green;
}

#mySidebar #btn4 {
  top: 30%;
}

#btn4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  right: 95%;
  font-size: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<div id="mySidebar">
  <button id="btn4" onclick="togglesidebar()">
    <span id="changeclass" class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span>
  </button>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just toggle both classes to change it

```
function togglesidebar() {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").classList.toggle('active')
    document.getElementById("changeclass").classList.toggle("fa-chevron-right");
    document.getElementById("changeclass").classList.toggle("fa-chevron-left");
}
```